# std::advance - offset out of range failure on Debug only

Tags: c++, std, stdvector

I'm trying to iterate through a vector by more than 1 using **std::advance**. There's a discrepancy between the Debug and Release builds with *Debug* giving the vector iterator + offset out of range failure while the Release works even in the real application in a more expanded case. Why does this happen and how can I write it so it runs on Debug?

```
vector<glm::vec2> testV;
testV.push_back(glm::vec2(0.f));
int step = 2;

for (auto it = testV.begin(); it != testV.end(); )
{
    if (it + step <= testV.end())
        advance(it, step);

    else
        ++it;
}
```

this also runs on Release (unless I print something in the loop which causes a hang)

```
for (auto it = testV.begin(); it != testV.end(); )
    advance(it, step);
```

Comment: *I'm trying to iterate through a vector by more than 1 using std::advance* -- This is a case where a `for` loop from 0 to `testV.size()` would have been a better option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The addition operator for the iterator is validating the returned iterator.  When you add 2 and go past the end, that will generate your error in debug.  The release build doesn't have these checks so it doesn't report a problem.

Having an iterator point past the end of a container is, I think Undefined Behavior.  Dereferencing it definitely is.

You'll have to check for going past the end some other way.